# Developer tool for network monitoring for S60 devices?

Tags: symbian, s60, carbide, s60-3rd-edition, s60-5th-edition

is there a developer tool or some developer application for Symbian S60 devices which would enable me sniff network packages and see what application uses GPRS and sends data?
Anything integrated in Carbide?

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out RConnectionMonitor class. It allows you to see connections count and what applications are using them - it shows their UIDs. But it's not 100% reliable.